# How loop an array and exec a field to get the part that matches correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, dictionary, exec

I have an array and need to iterate and get the part that matches with my regex, but I just get one right then one null then another right and repeat

Code:

```js
var numeroRegex = /\No.+[0-9]/g;
result = [
  {
   // field1...
   "calle": "Av. Tercer Anillo Periferico No. 151  Colonia Primavera"
  },{
   "calle": "Av. Tercer Anillo Periferico No. 151  Colonia Primavera"
  },{
   "calle": "Av. Tercer Anillo Periferico No. 151  Colonia Primavera"
  }
];

result.map(element => {
  console.log("calle: " + element.calle);
  calle = numeroRegex.exec(element.calle);
  console.log(calle);
});
```

Comment: The `g` modifier changes `lastIndex` property hence you get that well-known behavior. Remove `g` since you need to obtain a single match per input string.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works just perfect. nd sorry for bad english :D